# NodeJS Passport - Twitter Info

Tags: node.js, twitter, passport-twitter

I have twitter authentication working correctly, however I need more than just the username and display name which is only what Passport is restricted to.

I am trying to do this:

```
var newUser =  new User();
newUser.uid = profile.id;
newUser.token = token;
newUser.username = profile.username;
newUser.displayName = profile.displayName;
newUser.profile_image_url = profile.profile_image_url;
```

If was looking at the passport documentation and it restricts the data you can use. I'm guessing so that it is consistent if you are using multiple authentication methods, but I only need to use twitter.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({ ... },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
    ....
  }
);
```

If I just log the profile then it gives all the data so i'm confused how I can get around it. I need the complete data from twitter, not just a few that passport picks out for me, how can i get this?

Comment: According to [this line in the source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/blob/2f73db79d47ed7c01316320b7fa6a0195fe96729/lib/strategy.js#L134), there should be a `profile._raw` and a `profile._json` property with all of [the data that twitter's API returns](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show). Can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution which works fine for me:

```
var image_url = profile._json.profile_image_url.replace('_normal','');
```

I know that removing the _normal from the string like that may not be the best way logically but it works and stores the original image url in the DB.